# Apache Camel Rest 503 Error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-camel

I've created a rest call using camel. This is configured to use camel servlet component and I'm using tomcat.

When hitting the rest api URL, I get a few successful responses (approx. 5-10 requests), but then after that it gets a 503 error. According to camel, this exchange has completed. The logs all show that it has been completed but then the client is hanging and waiting for a response.

I cannot find what is going wrong as I cant believe this is an issue with the application itself as there are successful responses, but we have not had this issue before using Spring Rest (which we are using for a different application)

Does anyone have any ideas? I can give more information on request

Comment: 503 is a server side issue. Try calling multiple times through any tool like SOAPUI or POSTMAN and then compare the results.

Comment: I'm using both of those which both give a 503 error which i know is a service unavailable error

Comment: Can you try calling the service from a different network ? Mostly, this does not look like client issue. The server may have restricted no of connections from a client per unit time.

Comment: the service is only available on the network so cannot do that

Comment: Then as I told you the issue is probably on Server side. Ask them if they have  The restricted no of connections from a client per unit time. Ex 10 per minute

Comment: How can I find these details?